# How to fix " The property is set more than once"?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my list view, When I expand my listview I want show to many controls but when I assign Isvisible property's to label I get this error "The property "text" is shown more than once "

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Class="CpoLogin.MainPage">

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Complains}"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      Margin="40,80"
                      ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ComplainsTitle}"/>
                            <Label Text="Caller CNIC: 4220142488449"/>
                            <Label Text="Complaint Type: Emergency"/>
                            <Label Text="Notes: Gulshan-e-Iqal,Karachi"/>
                            <Label Text="Criminals Involved: 2"/>
                            <Label Text="Dead Count: 2"/>
                            <Label Text="Sub Type: Murder"/>
                            <Label Text="Criminal Appearance: 2"/>
                            <Label Text="Wounded Count: 2"/>
                            <Label Text="Vehicle Used: 2"
                                   IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}/>



                            <Button Text="Details"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"/>

                        </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

    </ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Aashir Khan

Please replace the following code

```
<Label Text="Vehicle Used: 2"
       IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" />
```

You forgot to close the double quotes, please check and accept the answer if helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Content instead of text for buttons.

Comment: Content won't work for Forms, it should be Text only.

Comment: Ah, my bad! I thought the question was about WPF.

Comment: And event if it *was* possible, this is in now way related to the question asked.